# Is it possible to disable writes, updates and deletes from web admin console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Is it possible to disable writes, updates and deletes from web admin console? ( Allowed Read Only )

I want write, update or delete from client side only ( Using Code Only )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to disable writes, updates and deletes from web admin
> console?

With "web admin console" I guess you are speaking about the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/).

If you want to assign to a user a read-only permission, in such a way he/she can only view (but not modify) existing data, you can assign the **Viewer** role to this user. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-basic).

Comment: Yes I was mean Firebase Console. About viewer roleI can modifying from client side ( using code )?

Comment: I've never tried but it may be possible through IAM [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/libraries) or the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest).